# Using JSON input in Ruby method on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am using jQuery to make an AJAX call to a ruby method in my controller. The javascript looks something like this:

```
var latLongJSON = {
  "address": [{
    "lat": 50,
    "long": 50
  }]
};

var returnedAddresses;

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  data: latLongJSON,
  url: "map/getaddresses",
  success: function(data) {
    returnedAddresses = JSON.parse(data);
  }
});
```

Then in my 'getaddresses' method, my parameter coming through looks like:

```
Parameters: {"address"=>"[object Object]"}
```

I'm not sure what to do with this. I'm fairly new to Ruby, and I'm not sure if I need to convert this to something else, or what. Ideally I want to be able to pass in multiple sets of lat/long in the 'address' array, then be able to iterate over those in my Ruby code.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I think 1.3.2 - it's what came with jRails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out jQuery 1.4.2, it as much better handling of passing objects back to the server.

The [param function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) was rewritten in 1.4.* to handle padding back deep arrays and object.

Comment: Looks like that helped quite a bit, but I'm still not sure how to handle the parameters:

Parameters: {"address"=>{"0"=>{"lat"=>"50", "long"=>"50"}}}

Do I need to convert that into a Hash, or how else would I iterate over it?

Comment: Nevermind - that was my Ruby newbieness shining through. That is in a hashmap. Thanks for the suggestion.